# Loop not working between directories

Tags: vba, excel

I worked around with a vba code to search a list of cells in a column of a workbook and those cells need to be searched in a folder and if cell is matched in any of the workbook all corresponding data needs to be copied to the main workbook.

I was working with 2 loops but if one is working another one is not for example if I loop through all files in a folder I can't loop with the column in the main workbook to search one cell after another.

Below is the code:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim irow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strPath = "\dfs\Home\Tes"

    Set wOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With wOut
    lRow = 2
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")

        Do While Cells(lRow, 1) < Empty
            strSearch = Cells(lRow, 1)
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
                (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
                UpdateLinks:=0, _
                ReadOnly:=True, _
                AddToMRU:=False)

            For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
                Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If rFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                     Else
                        Cells(lRow, 2) = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    End If
                    Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
                Loop While strFirstAddress < rFound.Address
            Next

            wbk.Close (False)
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Loop
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the do while to

```
  Do While .Cells(lRow, 1) <> Empty
```

Explanation: If you use `Cells(lRow, 1)` (without dot), you access the active sheet. But in the moment you do a `workbook.open`, the active sheet will change, so at the next iteration you no longer look to the sheet `wOut` but to a sheet of the opened wokbook.

If you write `.Cells(lRow, 1)` (with leading dot), `Cells` is seen as a property of whatever you have used in a `with`-clause, in your case `With wOut`. Alternatively, you could write `wOut.Cells(lRow, 1)` (this is just a matter of taste)

Comment: Actually this code does not loop with all files the folder. It only access the first file. I want it to loop all files in the folder one after another as well.

Comment: I just need the code to search all files in that folder for the matching data! I am not able to work with the code for that.

Comment: To loop over a list of files with the fileSytemObject, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683516/7599798 . Or you could use the VBA `dir` command

Comment: Since I am new to vba I want to know how I can put that code in my code to work properly with the loop.

Comment: I would split the code: One sub to loop over the files, and within a loop call another sub (with the filename or an already opened workbook as parameter) that handles the work with one file.

Comment: I would try this out definitely as per my understanding. But if possible it would be great if you call tell me alterations in my code it would make my life much easier. Thank u.